# Show that $T$ does not have any fixed points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ if and only if $T(P)=P+T(0)$, $\forall P\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Tags: geometry

So $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is an orientation-preserving rigid motion with $T(0)\neq 0$.

What is a good way to prove this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, if $T(P)=P+T(0)$ for all $P$ and $T(0)\ne 0$, then $T$ has no fixed points.

Now assume there is a point $A\ne0$ with $T(A)\ne A+T(0)$.
There is a unique reflection $R_1$ that take $0\mapsto T(0)$. Let $A'=R_1(A)$. Then $d(T(0),T(A))=d(0,A)=d(T(0),A')$, i.e., $T(0)$ is on the perpendicular bisector $\ell$ of $AT(A)$. Let $R_2$ be the reflection at $\ell$. Then $R_2\circ R_1$ is an orientation preserving rigid motion that maps $0\mapsto T(0)$ and $A\mapsto T(A)$. Conclude that $T=R_2\circ R_1$.

If the axes of $R_1$ and $R_2$ are parallel, verify that $T$ is a translation.
Hence by assumption, the axes *do* intersect in some point $B$. Then $B$ is fix under both $R_1$ and $R_2$, hence is a fixed point of $T.